# Loop in rmarkdown

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, r-markdown

I am relatively new to r and rmarkdown so I apologise in advance if this is a stupid question. This is a simple replication of a bigger dataset.

I have three columns in a dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame( c(a, b), c(c, d), c(e, NA))
names(df) <- c("X", "Y", "Z")
```

I want to show them in a rmarkdown file as follows:

I like a b.

This is c

This is e

This is d

I have written a function that includes

```
X <- 0
  for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  X[i] <- df$X[[i]] }

Y <- 0
  for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  Y[i] <- df$Y[[i]] }

X <- 0 
  for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  Z[i] <- df$Z[[i]] }
```

And in the markdown file (the bit I'm struggling with)

````
I like `r X`    ### This is fine

``` {r}
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  Y[i]
  Z[i] }        ### Doesn't work and I want to include text i.e. This is
```
````

I want to make some sort of loop so it prints the element in row 1 of column Y then Z, then the next row etc. and skip ifNA

Any help whatsoever would be majorly appreciated! :)

Comment: `y <-c(1,2,NA,3); z<-c(4,5,NA,6); print(paste("This is", paste(y[which(!is.na(y))],z[which(!is.na(z))],collapse=" ")));`

Answer (score -1):

First, I'd give you some tips in your first loop. If you want to pass a data.frame column to a vector, you can vectorize it. I recommend you [check this later](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2014/04/why-writing-vectorized-code-in-r-is-a-good-idea.html). Hence, instead of:

```
X <- 0
 for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
     X[i] <- df$X[[i]] }
```

try to do:

```
X <- vector("numeric", nrow(df)) #suggestion to create a empty numerical vector
X <- as.numeric(df$X)
```

Answering your main question, you can name your code chunk to keep the things organized. Use `eval=FALSE` if you desire only the output and not the code printed. Now, you have your vectors and can use [@jason](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3896657/jason) suggestion:

````
I like `r X`


```{r code_chunk1, eval=FALSE}
paste0("This is ", X)
paste0("This is ", Y)
paste0("This is ", paste(Z,collapse = " ")) # if you want them all in the same line
}
```
````

Avoid the operator, it can produce unexpected results and create problems without you noticing! [Visit this.](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/five-tips-r-code-improve)

Answer (score -1):

There is no need to use loops. However, the elements of `df` need to be re-arranged to get printed row-wise.

The rmarkdown file below reproduces the expected result:

````
---
title: Loop in rmarkdown
output: html_document
---

```{r, echo=FALSE}
df <- data.frame( c("a", "b"), c("c", "d"), c("e", NA))
names(df) <- c("X", "Y", "Z")
```

I like `r df$X`

```{r, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(magrittr)                  # use piping to improve readability
df[, 2:3] %>%                      # treat columns like a matrix
  t() %>%                          # change from row first to column first order
  as.vector() %>%                  # flatten into vector
  na.omit() %>%                    # drop NAs
  paste("This is", .) %>%          # Prepend text
  knitr::kable(col.names = NULL)   # print as table
```
````

The output is

[image]

Note that `knitr::kable(col.names = NULL)` is used to create inline text, i.e., text output not wrapped in a verbatim element.

Alternatively, the chunk option `results='asis'` can be used:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, results='asis'}
library(magrittr)                              # use piping to improve readability
df[, 2:3] %>%                                  # treat columns like a matrix
  t() %>%                                      # change from row first to column first order
  as.vector() %>%                              # flatten into vector
  na.omit() %>%                                # drop NAs
  paste("This is", ., collapse = "  \n") %>%   # Prepend text and collapse into one string
  cat()                                        # use cat() instead of print()
```
````

Note that the 2 blanks before `\n` are required to indicate a line break in rmarkdown.